# Evaluating $\sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{k(1-e)^k}$

Tags: hypergeometric-function, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Question :

[image]

My attempt:

Let $a=17399172$
$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{\log_2\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(\ln\left(e^{C_j^k}\right)\right)\right)(1-e)^k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{\log_2\left(\sum_{j=0}^{k}\left(C_j^k\right)\right)(1-e)^k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{\log_2\left(2^k\right)(1-e)^k} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{k(1-e)^k} \\
\end{align}$$

Can you give me some hints what to do afterwards? I'll try by myself.

Comment: Where is this monster coming from ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i got from facebook. Question is by Sir Fajer Almohamad

Comment: I know what I should do with such a problem : I should just cry !! Back to serious, I wait for an answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hint: The solution can be found from these two expressions $\sum _{k=1}^n H_k z^k$ and $\int_0^y \frac{z^k}{z} \, dz= y^k/k$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a full answer but I will elaborate on @Dr.WolfgangHintze comments. We have
$$
\begin{align}
S
&= \sum_{k=1}^{a}\frac{-1-H_k}{k(1-e)^k}\\
&= -\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}(1+H_{k+1})\frac{(\frac{1}{1-e})^{k+1}}{k+1} \\
&= -\int_0^{\frac{1}{1-e}}\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}(1+H_{k+1})t^k\,\mathrm dt\\
&=: -\int_0^{\frac{1}{1-e}}S^\ast(t)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{align}
$$
Now write
$$
\begin{align}
S^\ast(t)
&= \sum_{k=0}^{a-1}(1+H_{k+1})t^k\\
&= \frac{1-t^a}{1-t}+\sum_{k=0}^{a-1}H_{k+1}t^k\\
&= \frac{1-t^a}{1-t}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty H_{k+1}t^k-\sum_{k=a}^\infty H_{k+1}t^k\\
&= \frac{1-t^a}{1-t}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty H_{k+1}t^k-\sum_{k=0}^\infty H_{a+k+1}t^{a+k}.
\end{align}
$$
Working with the [recurrence relations](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/HarmonicNumber/17/01/02/0001/) for the harmonic numbers as well as the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) we find
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty H_{a+k+1}t^{a+k}
&=t^a\sum_{k=0}^\infty (H_a+\sum_{\ell=1}^{k+1}\frac{1}{a+\ell})t^k\\
&=t^a\left(\frac{H_a}{1-t}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{1}{a+1+\ell}t^k\right)\\
&=\frac{t^a}{1-t}\left(H_a+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{a+1+k}t^k\right)\\
&=\frac{t^a}{1-t}\left(H_a+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_k\Gamma(a+1+k)}{\Gamma(a+2+k)}\frac{t^k}{k!}\right)\\
&=\frac{t^a}{1-t}\left(H_a+\frac{1}{1+a}F\left({1,1+a\atop 2+a};t\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$
Setting $a=0$ gives the closed form for the other series term and so
$$
\begin{align}
S^\ast(t)
&= \frac{1-t^a}{1-t}-\frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t}-\frac{t^a}{1-t}\left(H_a+\frac{1}{1+a}F\left({1,1+a\atop 2+a};t\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
S
&= -\int_0^{\frac{1}{1-e}} \frac{1-t^a}{1-t}-\frac{\log(1-t)}{1-t}-\frac{t^a}{1-t}\left(H_a+\frac{1}{1+a}F\left({1,1+a\atop 2+a};t\right)\right)\,\mathrm dt.
\end{align}
$$
Most of the integrals are easy to evaluate with the exception of the integral involving the hypergeometric function which will take a little extra work.